# Multiple rotations on UIButton

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I want to rotate a UIButton multiple times with the same degree every time (90°). The issue I'm having is that it performs one 90° spin then the next time I press the button it starts from 0 again and goes to the same, previous value. My code;

```
let rotateView = CABasicAnimation()

    rotateView.toValue = 90 * (M_PI) / 180

    rotateView.duration = 0
    rotateView.repeatCount = 0
    rotateView.removedOnCompletion = false
    rotateView.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    rotateView.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    smile2.layer.addAnimation(rotateView, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")
```

I think the problem may be that I can't specify the `fromValue` as I use a random number to begin with - here is the code;

```
let value: NSArray = [90, 180, 270, 360]
    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(value.count)
    let randomNumber = Double(arc4random_uniform(range))
```

To make it extra clear: The button's `fromValue` is a random number in the `let value`. I want to make the button spin 90° from that random number continuously at every button press.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is partly these lines:

```
rotateView.removedOnCompletion = false
rotateView.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
```

That sort of thing is just a crutch, and shows that you don't really understand how animation works. You are leaving out a crucial step, and covering up that failure with those lines. The crucial step is that you must set the view's `transform` to the same value that the animation is going to give it. Once you do that, those lines will be unnecessary, and successive animations will work correctly.

Also note that your life will be a lot simpler if you use *additive* animation, since you can then just rotate 90 degrees from wherever you are.